# How to fetch an image from one bucket and put it in another in S3 boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to fetch an image from one bucket(bucket1) and put it another bucket (bucket2)
I have written the below code snippet in python which I am trying,but I am getting the error:IOError: cannot identify image file.Please help.Thanks!

```
 conn = boto.connect_s3()
 filename='image2.jpg'
 bucket=conn.get_bucket('bucket1')
 key= bucket.get_key(filename)
 fp = open (filename, "w+")
 key.get_file (fp)


img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())
im = Image.open(img)

b = conn.get_bucket('bucket2')
k = b.new_key('image2.jpg')
k.set_contents_from_string(out_im2.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `copy_key` to avoid downloading and writing the object:

```
b = conn.get_bucket('bucket2')
k = b.copy_key('image2.jpg', 'bucket1', 'image2.jpg')
```

As you want to do some image processing you need to seek back to the beginning of the file after writing the file:

```
fp.seek(0, 0)
img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())
im = Image.open(img)

b = conn.get_bucket('bucket2')
k = b.new_key('image2.jpg')
k.set_contents_from_string(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I want to fetch it,resize it and then put it in bucket2(I have not written the intermediate code for resizing it yet)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use fp in `Image.open(fp)`, what is Image - `from PIL import Image`? And do you need to add `b` to the open mode for binary on `fp`

Comment: Which library is `Image` coming from, it's not a part of python's standard library?

Comment: Yes it is.I did from PIL import Image,still its giving me the same error

Comment: Image file is getting downloaded properly in the folder where i had stored this code but it is giving the same error at the line "im=Image.open(img)"

Comment: Have you tried opening fp as binary `b`? And using fp directly? And seek back to the beginning `fp.seek(0, 0)`

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to do it.Will you please elaborate